# When I click multiple listbox dynamic textbox must be generated Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, dom-events

Here I have multiple listbox and when I click an option dynamic textbox should be generated Javascript.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function changeFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedValue);
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="selectBox" multiple onchange="changeFunc();">
   <option value="1">Option #1</option>
   <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `dynamic textbox must be generated` where to generate it?

Comment: under the listbox,textbox should be created for each click in listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using JS Core:

```
function changeFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    input.type = text;
    document.getElementbyId('input_fields').appendChild(input);
}
```

Add the following div to your body

```
<div id="input_fields"></div>
```

The Solution becomes much easier if you use jQuery:

```
function changeFunc() {
    $("#input_fields").append("<input type='text' value='"+$("#selectBox").val()+"'>");
}
```

This will simply append the HTML inside the div with id="input_fields"

Answer (score 1):

is this you want?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFunc() {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var textP = document.createElement('p');
        textP.innerHTML = selectedValue;
        document.body.appendChild(textP);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="selectBox" multiple onchange="changeFunc();">
        <option value="1">Option #1</option>
        <option value="2">Option #2</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```